# Laravel Eloquent sum throwing error

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

I'm just simply want to sum column . 
I used this code

```
$money = Income::sum('money');
```

also tired this

```
$money = Income::select(DB::raw('sum(money)'))->get();
```

but it's throwing error . I'm using postgresql as my database . 
Error message :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: select sum("money") as aggregate from "incomes"
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select sum("money") as aggregate from "incomes")
```

my table :

```
incomes

+----+---------+-------+
| id | orderid | money |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |    2343 |    23 |
|  2 |    2344 |    55 |
+----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: can you post database schema?

Comment: @Jaimin edited post

Comment: That's not quite the schema; can you post the database migration file that builds the income table? Or using psql, can you run `\d {income table name}` and share the result?

Comment: Solved @ChrisForrence . It was my mistake . I made column string instead integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your error message, the `sum` method doesn't take in a varchar (character varying). It sounds like the `money` column is not a number datatype (though it my solely consist of numeric values.

To work around this, cast the value to a numeric data type:

```
Income::select(DB::raw('sum(cast(money as double precision))'))->get()
```

Note that this will not necessarily be performant. You may consider changing the database schema (if possible) to store money as an integer and as cents in the database. That is, 1000 in the database would reflect $10.00.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum using this

```
$money = DB::table('incomes')->sum('money');
```

Check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries