# No function matches the given name and argument types, what does it mean. Project is working fine locally, but throwing this error on heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, hosting

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: select sum("amount") as aggregate from "payments"
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select sum("amount") as aggregate from "payments")

PDOException
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function sum(character varying) does not exist LINE 1: select sum("amount") as aggregate from "payments" ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It's a Laravel Project and working fine locally, but throwing this error on Heroku, please kindly assist.

This is my code: `$totalAmount = DB::table('payments')->sum('amount');`

Its working fine locally.

Comment: `"amount"` is a string. Column name is `amount`

Comment: You are probably using PostreSQL

Comment: Please, elaborate more

Comment: @MrEduar, yes. Any suggestion?

Comment: `amount` column Is it of type string or varchar?

Comment: @MrEduar, it's string.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38743700/13522473

Answer (score 0):

For others facing this same issue.

Firstly, sum() does not accept varchar or string( if your column data type is varchar/string you will get that error ).

1. You can change your data type to integer or double( or the likes ).
2. Write you code like this $totalAmount = Payment::select(DB::raw('sum(cast(amount as double))'))->get(); ( remember get() will return and array )

or $totalAmount = DB::raw('SUM(amount)'); instead of $totalAmount = DB::table('payments')->sum('amount'); ( but you can write it like this if you will go for the first option to change data type)

For me I changed data type to integer and use this $totalAmount = DB::table('payments')->sum('amount');